# Prove that if the sum of $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ and the difference of vectors $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ are perpendicular

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors

Here's the full problem:

Prove that if the sum of $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ and the difference of vectors $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ are perpendicular, then the magnitude of $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ must be equivalent.

Okay, so i have tried going through the branch of the formula for perpendicular vectors sum $\ \vec{a}+\vec{b}=\sqrt{|\vec{a}|^2+|\vec{b}|^2}$$ but i don't think this works though.
I would like to see an approach without using dot prodcut of 2 perpendicular vectors being 0.

Comment: The problem with your approach is that you're equating a vector of the left-hand side while there's a scalar on the right-hand side. The Pythagorean theorem is not a fundamental theorem about vectors, it is a consequence of the magnitude of vectors which follows when vectors are perpendicular.

Comment: So any solution is equivalent to the dot/scalar product being zero, which is itself a consequence of Pythagoras. The scalar product version can be proved from Pythagoras using a basis for the vector space. The advantage of the scalar product when dealing with vectors is that it is a basis-free formulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have, for the dot product $\langle .,. \rangle$,
$$\langle a+b, a-b \rangle = 0$$

so
$$\langle a, a\rangle -\langle a, b\rangle +\langle b, a\rangle -\langle b, b\rangle =0$$

and because $\langle a, b\rangle =\langle b ,a \rangle $, you deduce that
$$\langle a,a \rangle =\langle b , b\rangle $$

**Edit** : If you want another way of proving that, apply Pythagorean theorem to $a+b$ and $a-b$, which are perpendicular. You get that
$$|a+b+a-b|^2 = |a+b|^2+|a-b|^2$$

so

$$4|a|^2 = |a|^2+|b|^2+2 \langle a,b \rangle + |a|^2+|b|^2-2 \langle a,b \rangle$$

so $$|a|^2 = |b|^2$$

Comment: Well, Op clearly stated he wants a different approach than the vector dot product being equal to 0.

Comment: My bad ! I did not see the last part.

Comment: @AnanyapamDe No, I am not doing what you say I do.

Comment: Wanted to add that comment to the question itself, Sorry

Comment: Nevermind, i got it, that was a cool approach too, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[image]

You can use geometry. Vectors $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ form a paralelogram (as the Figure) and $\vec a+ \vec b$ and $\vec a- \vec b$ are the diagonals.

We know that these diagonals cut itself in the middle point. So $BI=DI$. If $CI$ is perpendicular to $BD$ then the triangles $BIC$ and $CID$ are congruents and then $BC=CD$.

Comment: but your drawing does not use that a-b (vectors) and a+b (vectors) are perpendicular, does it?

Comment: @Al3diumGD: the drawing is general. I use this information when I say that $CI$ is perpendicular to $BD$.

Comment: your approach is so interesting i like it so much, just adding one thing: can the triangles BIC and CID, be used pythagoras to reach to the same conclusion that BC=CD or not?

Comment: @Al3diumGD: Yep! You can use it!

Comment: okay great! and how would i express the pythag like? As (NOTE: all the a and b that i write now are vectors) 
(a+b)^2+(a-b)^2=b^2
and 
(a+b)^2+(a-b)^2=a^2
like this?

Comment: @Al3diumGD, almost. The vector $IC$ is equal to $(a+b)/2$ and the vectors $IB$ and $DI$ are equal to $(a-b)/2$.

Comment: oh, right, is (a+b) in absolute parens? like is it the a+b vectors surrounded by abs vars?

Comment: @Al3diumGD, when you deal with the size of it, so yes.

Comment: okay i got it thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The dot product of sum and difference vectors vanish due to their being mutually  perpendicular.

$$(\vec a+\vec b)\cdot(\vec a-\vec b)=0$$
Multiply term by term
$$(\vec a\cdot\vec a)-(\vec b \cdot \vec b)-(\vec a\cdot\vec b)+(\vec a \cdot\vec b)=0$$
$$ |a|^2-|b|^2 =0$$
$$ |a|=|b|$$

EDIT1

Ok then geometrically with trig:

Slopes of sum, diff of vectors in a parallelogram

$$\tan \theta_1=\dfrac{b \sin \theta}{a+ b \cos \theta} $$
$$\tan \theta_2=\dfrac{b \sin \theta}{a- b \cos \theta} $$

[image]

Product of LHS tans is $-1$

$$\dfrac{b^2 \sin^2 \theta}{a^2- b^2 \cos^2  \theta}=-1$$

Cross multiply, transpose to simplify discard $a+b=0$ solution getting
$$a=b.$$

Comment: i said i did not want a dot product=0 approach, but thanks as well

Comment: Duh, somehow did not see it..